# Emacs config file when installed using snap

Tags: config, ubuntu

I installed Emacs 26 on Ubuntu using snap.

Where to find the Emacs configuration file in this context ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have opened Emacs you can see what is your *emacs directory* by checking the value of the variable `user-emacs-directory`.

Just: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `user-emacs-directory`.

Inside that directory an `init.el` should be the configuration file. If that doesn't work, you should check `~/.emacs` or `~/.emacs.el` files.

You can also find [more details in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html).